# Why is my JSoup request returning an empty page?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Im trying to connect to a website at

```
siDoc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.streetinsider.com").get();
```

and it is returning

```
 <html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please provide the complete `java` code

Comment: im just asking if jsoup works on pages that are .php

Comment: yes, it does. jsoup doesn't care about the extension.

Comment: ok here is the code, every other site works but this returns empty

Comment: I don't see any `.php` in your string

Comment: the whole domain is not working, can you tell me why this returns empty ond not the entire doc?

Comment: other websites work fine in this code except this site

Comment: What happen when you open this link in your browser? Maybe they just blocked your ip

Comment: works fine ... thats why i asked

Comment: You should check the headers you send/receive

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Don't just post your actual question as the title. That confuses people reading the question. Make sure you ask the specific question, in this case, "Why is my request returning an empty page?" in the body of the question. And later in the comments you said "im just asking if jsoup works on pages that are .php", that too should be in the question section. It's important you make it as clear and easy for people trying to help you to do so, and not waste their time or come here with hubris. Please edit the question and clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `userAgent`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.streetinsider.com").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```